# Echo whole table without using column names as ref

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I really hope someone can help,

I have a table with one row and multiple column names, one of these being id, I want to echo the whole table without using the column names as reference as these might change and I don’t want to have to go in and change the code if a column gets added or taken away. i.e. I want to `SELECT * from table WHERE id=1` then echo the whole table, not including the id column or any column titles.

I’m a bit stumped and not sure where to look for the right answer, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance being trying to get my head around this all weekend.

Brill thanks for all the help got it sorted, for anyone who wants my solution:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * from nav WHERE id='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $i=1;

    while($i<=500)
    {
    echo $row[$i]  . "<br />";
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: You want something like var_dump()?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_result::fetch_row` instead of `mysqli_result::fetch_array` as it will return an indexed array of values.

Example:

```
$result  = $mysqli->query($query)
$columns = $mysqli->field_count;
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    for($i = 5; $i < $columns; ++$i)
      echo $row[$i] . ", ";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Edit: updated to start from column 5 as requested in comments

Comment: Brilliant totally pointed me in the right direction, I now have:

        $sql = "SELECT * from nav WHERE id='1'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        echo $row[5];

However I want to echo from row[5] to the end of the table without putting all the column numbers in as this may change, i was hoping I would be able to do something like, echo row[5] to end of table or echo row[5] to 2000 (a number that would never be achieved) 

Any thought would be greatly appreciated thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT id AS no_title, column1 AS ... FROM table WHERE id=1`

I don't see your point why you want to do this, but you can always choose an alias, I haven't tried `AS " "` yet, though...